# Is there any profit in using contiguous space in lvm?

Tags: lvm

When creating an LVM on linux, there's couple of options to set up. One of them is `-C y`, which sets contiguous space that a logical volume can use. Should I use this parameter or not? I know that you can't simply resize/move the volumes when you use the option, but are there any other pros or cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to avoid "-C" if it is possible. With this flag activated, LVM uses only blocks next to each other on the same physical drive.

The idea behind LVM ist to remove these restrictions. You only need it, if you bundle different drives together but a special logical volume need to be on one disk (e.g. SSD).

So: don't use it as lg as you don't need it!

Comment: Do contiguous blocks affect read/write speed somehow, or are they useful in any other way?

Comment: Not directly. But if every block is on the same physical disk, this can make some things faster if you need it. (SWAP)